# (C++) Template code for adding tagging types to add additional context

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

Below is a piece of template code which allows for adding a Tag to structure or class types.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <concepts>

//Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31171682/type-trait-for-copying-cv-reference-qualifiers
// Copies the const and volatile qualifiers from T to U;
// Example copy_cv< const double, float >::type == const float  
template<typename T,typename U>
struct copy_cv
{
    private:
        using R = std::remove_reference_t<T>;
        using U1 = std::conditional_t<std::is_const<R>::value, std::add_const_t<U>, U>;
        using U2 = std::conditional_t<std::is_volatile<R>::value, std::add_volatile_t<U1>, U1>;
    public:
        using type = U2;
};

// Checks if a type is basicly the same as another ( ignoring const and volatile )
template< typename cvrefT, typename T >
concept basicly = std::is_same_v< std::remove_cvref_t< cvrefT >, T >;

// Checks if a type is a parent ( inheritance ) of another type
template< typename Base, typename Child >
concept parent_of = std::derived_from< Child, Base >;

// Code for converting between a tagged type and its base type
template< template<typename> typename Tag, typename Base >
struct TagConversion
{
    template< basicly< Base > U >
    static typename copy_cv< U, Tag< Base > >::type && Convert( U && u ){ return ( typename copy_cv< U, Tag< Base > >::type && ) u; } 
    template< parent_of< Base > T >
    explicit(false) operator T & () { return reinterpret_cast< T & >( *this ); }
};

// Combination of conversion + inheritance( to allow access to methods )
template< template<typename> typename Tag, typename Base >
struct TagProxy: public TagConversion< Tag, Base >, public Base {};

// Convenience method to quickly tag a type
template< template<typename> typename Tag, typename Base >
auto && Convert( Base && base ){ return Tag< typename std::remove_cvref_t< Base > >::Convert( base ); }
```

For example this could be used in the context of rendering where a point can be specified in world, screen, uv, camera, etc coordinates.

Example:

```
template< typename T >
struct WorldSpace: TagProxy< WorldSpace, T > {};

template< typename T >
struct ScreenSpace: TagProxy< ScreenSpace, T > {};

/// ======================================================== ///

struct Point
{
    double x;
    double y;
};

// With Context
ScreenSpace< Point > ToScreenSpace( WorldSpace< Point > const & inPoint )
{
    return Convert< ScreenSpace >( Point{ inPoint.x * 2, inPoint.y * 2 } );
}
```

This would avoid passing coordinates to a function which are defined in the wrong target space by having the code not compile.

My Questions:

- I know of the limitation that this cannot be used with types such as `int` ( as you cannot derive from them ). But are there any other potential issues that I haven't spotted yet
- From my limited experiments, I would suspect that code using these templates and plain code is compiled to the same binary. Thus resulting in no performance overhead. But I'm not sure.
- Could I give a nice error if a user tries to make `WorldSpace<int>`?
- Could I enforce that an Tag ( such as `WorldSpace` ) does not "extend" the class ( i.e. has member variables )?

Any other improvements are also welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Missing test suite

You have a very basic example, but are you sure your code handles all the edge cases you want it to handle? And do they all make sense?

For example, the following does not compile:

```
volatile Point point{1, 2};
auto tagged_point = Convert<WorldSpace>(point);
```

It works if you remove `volatile`. The following does compile:

```
const Point point{1, 2};
auto tagged_point = Convert<WorldSpace>(point);
```

But while you went to great lengths to copy the cv qualifiers, the resulting `tagged_point` is *not* `const`. This is because cv qualifiers don't really make sense when you return something *by value*; after all, the caller can always copy them into some variable with different qualifications.

## The interface is confusing

It's easy to create a new `Point`:

```
Point point{1, 2};
```

But how do you create a `WorldSpace<Point>`? I think most people would try this first:

```
WorldSpace<Point> world_point{1, 2};
```

But that doesn't compile, and your compiler will probably say something like "initializer must be brace-enclosed", which is not a very helpful error message as you did write braces there. The actual problem is that you don't have enough braces; it only compiles when you write this:

```
WorldSpace<Point> world_point{{{}, {1, 2}}};
```

That does not look very great though. So to keep your sanity, you can instead use `Convert<>()` to create a new tagged object:

```
auto world_point = Convert<WorldSpace>(Point{1, 2});
```

But now you are conflating *adding* a tag with *changing* a tag. I would create two functions, one with unconditionally adds a tag to a type, and another which just changes the outer tag. So consider:

```
auto world_point = add_tag<WorldSpace>(Point{1, 2});
auto screen_point = convert_tag<ScreenSpace>(world_point);
```

And make it so the following will fail to compile:

```
auto screen_point = convert_tag<ScreenSpace>(Point{1, 2});
```

But even better, make it look more like the standard library, and consider naming it `make_tagged<>()` and `tag_cast<>()`.

## Avoid unnecessary moves and copies

While your code will move objects where possible, a move still might have some overhead. It also requires that the object is movable. Even better would be to avoid that entirely. That might not be possible if you want to convert tagged objects, but tagging can be useful even if you never convert them. If you can make a `make_tagged<>()` function that constructs the inner object in-place, you will get the best performance, and at the same time also allow for objects that are neither copyable nor movable. Consider being able to write:

```
auto world_point = add_tag<WorldSpace, Point>(1, 2);
```

## Consider not using inheritance

Using inheritance gives you a way to transparently access the inner object. However, you will run into issues. You've already discovered that you can't use it with things like `int`. You also can't use it with `class`es that are marked `final`. There might be other corner cases where it will fail to work as expected. A much safer approach would be to avoid inheritance, and just store the inner object as a member variable, and overload `operator*()` and `operator->()` to let the user access it, just like you would for things like `std::unique_ptr<>`, `std::optional<>` and so on.

## Answers to your questions

> - I know of the limitation that this cannot be used with types such as `int` ( as you cannot derive from them ). But are there any other potential issues that I haven't spotted yet

I already mentioned some of those above, although there might be other issues I haven't spotted either.

> - From my limited experiments, I would suspect that code using these templates and plain code is compiled to the same binary. Thus resulting in no performance overhead. But I'm not sure.

Just compile it and look at the assembly output! Note that while the size of the tagged object is the same as the untagged object, there might be subtle issues that cause differences in performance. For example, depending on the inner object, the compiler might not be able to optimize away conversions. On the other hand, types with different tags cannot alias each other, so using tags might actually improve performance in some cases.

> - Could I give a nice error if a user tries to make `WorldSpace<int>`?

You can use either a [`requires` clause](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Requires_clauses) that checks for [`std::is_class<Base>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_class), or add a [`static_assert()` declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) that does the same. The latter allows for adding a custom error message, but a `requires` clause might be preferred as it will trigger earlier (with the `static_assert()` it will complain the error is inside the `TagProxy<>` template, whereas with the `requires` it will say the error is at the point where somebody wants to create a `WorldSpace<int>`).

> - Could I enforce that an Tag ( such as `WorldSpace` ) does not "extend" the class ( i.e. has member variables )?

You can use [`std::is_empty<Tag>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_empty) to check that the size of the tag is zero bytes. However, this still allows for member functions, and also there are ways to create variables that have a size of zero, so it's not failsafe. There is no way in C++ to check that it has no members at all.

However, even if the `Tag` has members, they are not exposed at all in the resulting tagged class, since you never actually derive directly from `Tag`, nor have a `Tag` as a member object. It's only part of the type as a template parameter.